# Reactjs new code not rendering to the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was working on a React application that I had to not work on for awhile.

I came back to it. I start up my local server using live-server public/

and no matter what I do on my `app.js` file, nothing renders. I can still see the last work I did on the browser, but my app.js file is having no impact in the browser even though what is rendering on the browser is from my app.js file. Honestly, I can never get used to this silent failure on the part of React. All the files are loading properly.

A colleague on Stack Overflow offered an answered that had worked which was to redo the `package.json` installation except do it with npm.

So I ran

`npm init`

Reinstalled with `npm install babel-preset-react babel-preset-env live-server`

and everything worked again. Its been some time since I worked on this application and now I am having the same problem again. Redoing the steps above is NOT working this time around.

This is my app.js file:

```
class DecisionTreeApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleDeleteOptions = this.handleDeleteOptions.bind(this);
    this.handlePick = this.handlePick.bind(this);
    this.handleAddOption = this.handleAddOption.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      options: []
    };
  }
  handleDeleteOptions() {
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        options: []
      };
    });
  }

  handlePick() {
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.options.length);
    const option = this.state.options[randomNum];
    alert(option);
  }

  handleAddOption(option) {
    if (!option) {
      return 'Enter valid value to add item';
    } else if (this.state.options.indexOf(option) > -1) {
      return 'This option already exists';
    }

    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        options: prevState.options.concat(option)
      };
    });
  }
  render() {
    const title = 'Decision Tree';
    const subtitle = 'For binary life decisions, put your trust in a computer';

    return (
      <div>
        <Header subtitle={subtitle} />
        <Action
          hasOptions={this.state.options.length > 0}
          handlePick={this.handlePick}
        />
        <Options
          options={this.state.options}
          handleDeleteOptions={this.handleDeleteOptions}
        />
        <AddOption handleAddOption={this.handleAddOption} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      <h2>{props.subtitle}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

Header.defaultProps = {
  title: 'some default title'
};

const Action = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={props.handlePick}
        disabled={!props.hasOptions}
      >
        What should I do?
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Options = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={props.handleDeleteOptions}>Remove All</button>
      {props.options.map(option => (
        <Option key={option} optionText={option} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Option = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.optionText}
    </div>
  )
};

class AddOption extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleAddOption = this.handleAddOption.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      error: undefined
    };
  }
  handleAddOption(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const option = e.target.elements.option.value.trim();
    const error = this.props.handleAddOption(option);

    this.setState(() => {
      return { error };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error}</p>}
        <form onSubmit={this.handleAddOption}>
          <input type="text" name="option" />
          <button>Add Option</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DecisionTreeApp />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

This is my file structure:

[image]

This is my `/public/scripts/app.js`:

```
'use strict';

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

var DecisionTreeApp = function (_React$Component) {
  _inherits(DecisionTreeApp, _React$Component);

  function DecisionTreeApp(props) {
    _classCallCheck(this, DecisionTreeApp);

    var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (DecisionTreeApp.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(DecisionTreeApp)).call(this, props));

    _this.handleDeleteOptions = _this.handleDeleteOptions.bind(_this);
    _this.handlePick = _this.handlePick.bind(_this);
    _this.handleAddOption = _this.handleAddOption.bind(_this);
    _this.state = {
      options: []
    };
    return _this;
  }

  _createClass(DecisionTreeApp, [{
    key: 'handleDeleteOptions',
    value: function handleDeleteOptions() {
      this.setState(function () {
        return {
          options: []
        };
      });
    }
  }, {
    key: 'handlePick',
    value: function handlePick() {
      var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.options.length);
      var option = this.state.options[randomNum];
      alert(option);
    }
  }, {
    key: 'handleAddOption',
    value: function handleAddOption(option) {
      if (!option) {
        return 'Enter valid value to add item';
      } else if (this.state.options.indexOf(option) > -1) {
        return 'This option already exists';
      }

      this.setState(function (prevState) {
        return {
          options: prevState.options.concat(option)
        };
      });
    }
  }, {
    key: 'render',
    value: function render() {
      var title = 'Decision Tree';
      var subtitle = 'For binary life decisions, put your trust in a computer';

      return React.createElement(
        'div',
        null,
        React.createElement(Header, { subtitle: subtitle }),
        React.createElement(Action, {
          hasOptions: this.state.options.length > 0,
          handlePick: this.handlePick
        }),
        React.createElement(Options, {
          options: this.state.options,
          handleDeleteOptions: this.handleDeleteOptions
        }),
        React.createElement(AddOption, { handleAddOption: this.handleAddOption })
      );
    }
  }]);

  return DecisionTreeApp;
}(React.Component);

var Header = function Header(props) {
  return React.createElement(
    'div',
    null,
    React.createElement(
      'h1',
      null,
      props.title
    ),
    React.createElement(
      'h2',
      null,
      props.subtitle
    )
  );
};

Header.defaultProps = {
  title: 'some default title'
};

var Action = function Action(props) {
  return React.createElement(
    'div',
    null,
    React.createElement(
      'button',
      {
        onClick: props.handlePick,
        disabled: !props.hasOptions
      },
      'What should I do?'
    )
  );
};

var Options = function Options(props) {
  return React.createElement(
    'div',
    null,
    React.createElement(
      'button',
      { onClick: props.handleDeleteOptions },
      'Remove All'
    ),
    props.options.map(function (option) {
      return React.createElement(Option, { key: option, optionText: option });
    })
  );
};

var Option = function Option(props) {
  return React.createElement(
    'div',
    null,
    props.optionText
  );
};

var AddOption = function (_React$Component2) {
  _inherits(AddOption, _React$Component2);

  function AddOption(props) {
    _classCallCheck(this, AddOption);

    var _this2 = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (AddOption.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(AddOption)).call(this, props));

    _this2.handleAddOption = _this2.handleAddOption.bind(_this2);
    _this2.state = {
      error: undefined
    };
    return _this2;
  }

  _createClass(AddOption, [{
    key: 'handleAddOption',
    value: function handleAddOption(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var option = e.target.elements.option.value.trim();
      var error = this.props.handleAddOption(option);

      this.setState(function () {
        return { error: error };
      });
    }
  }, {
    key: 'render',
    value: function render() {
      return React.createElement(
        'div',
        null,
        this.state.error && React.createElement(
          'p',
          null,
          this.state.error
        ),
        React.createElement(
          'form',
          { onSubmit: this.handleAddOption },
          React.createElement('input', { type: 'text', name: 'option' }),
          React.createElement(
            'button',
            null,
            'Add Option'
          )
        )
      );
    }
  }]);

  return AddOption;
}(React.Component);

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(DecisionTreeApp, null), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: It seems like this is most likely either a `live-server` or `webpack` (if you're even using webpack) issue, not a React issue. You may actually be able to just move your project over to `create-react-app` pretty easily, which would take care of your build/dev server issues.

Comment: @ShaneCavaliere, I am not using `webpack` and I am starting to suspect `live-server` as well. Any documentation on how to move my project over to `create-react-app`? Or do you just mean run `create-react-app` in my command line and start rebuilding it there?

Comment: Yeah, the easiest way would probably be to run `create-react-app` in your command line, and then just copy your project files over (CRA looks at `src/index.js` for the project root). If it's just that one app.js file, just rename it to index.js and put it in the src folder.

Comment: For small projects, I'd also recommend checking out codesandbox.io. It's awesome for putting together simple React projects really quickly without worrying about any config or setup. For instance, I just copied your code into a new sandbox, it it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/8plp6r942l. It's great for sharing your code on SO too, makes it easier for people to look at it and help you figure stuff out.

Comment: @ShaneCavaliere, will codesandbox.io, work when the time comes to deploy it to `Heroku`? This is what I want to eventually do.

Comment: No, you won't be able to deploy to Heroku from CodeSandbox (although they do have an integration that lets you deploy to ZEIT Now). It's mostly just a nice tool for messing around with toy projects, or sharing code. In your case, making a create-react-app project locally is probably what you'll want.

Comment: @ShaneCavaliere, please post your answer about `create-react-app` and thank you.

Comment: @Ale, can you post your file structure please.

Comment: @Daniel, I added my file structure.

Comment: @Ale, post for me whats inside `/public/scripts/app.js`.

Comment: @Daniel, posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alejandra, based on your setup, the reason your browser is not rendering because you need to transpile your code with babel just as at some point your app was doing inside of `/public/scripts/app.js`.

In order to do that you need to have two command line terminals available when you start your local server.

The one `live-server public` AND `babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets=env,react --watch` to do the transpiling as your writing your code.